# How to solve the non-linear PDE: $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t})^2=x^2(1+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})^2)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Actually, this equation came from the other question: What is the transformation matrix between the metric $diag(-x^2,1)$ and the usual Minkowski metric $diag(-1,1)$.

The results seems to be easy, $x'=x cosh(t)$ and $t'=x sinh(t)$. But I find problems when I try to separate the variables.

Is there any methods to solve the equation? Any comments will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t})^2=x^2(1+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})^2)$$
Separation of variables, in order to find a family of particular solutions :
$$f(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$$
$$(X\,T')^2=x^2(1+(X'T)^2)$$
$$\left(\frac{T'}{T}\right)^2-\left(\frac{xX'}{X} \right)^2-\left(\frac{x}{XT}\right)^2=0$$
The separation of variables is possible only if the mixed term $\frac{x}{XT}$ is function of $t$ only or function of $x$ only.

The case "function of $x$ only" is possible if $T(t)$=constant leading to trivial solution $f(x,t)=i\,x+c$ of no interest.

The case "function of $t$ only" is possible if $\frac{x}{X}$=constant $\quad\implies\quad X(x)=c\,x$
$$\left(\frac{T'}{T}\right)^2-1-\left(\frac{1}{c\,T}\right)^2=0$$
$$(T')^2-T^2=\frac{1}{c^2}$$
Solving the ODE leads to
$$T(t)=\frac{1}{c}\sinh(t+C)$$
$$f(x,t)=x\,\sinh(t+C)$$

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I do not notice that I can discuss X=cx from this way (I mean I just suppose it right). But I think the process that solve the ODE of T(t) has some problem, T(t) can be equal to $\frac{1}{2c}(a e^t - \frac{1}{a}e^{-t})$, and sinh is a special case that a=1

Comment: This is the same solution. $\frac{1}{2c}(ae^t-\frac{1}{a}e^{-t})=\frac{1}{c}\sinh(t+C)\quad$ with $\quad a=e^C$ .

Comment: ah yes, that is right, I did not notice that there is a constant, very thankful to your reply!